PDFjs and page enumeration
I have the following problem. I would like to open PDFs like this on a certain cited page:
https://slub.qucosa.de/api/qucosa%3A89546/attachment/ATT-0/
As you can see, the page enumeration and page number are different.

For jumping to the right page, I would need the page enumeration. Is there any way, to access the enumeration-information? So that I know, that page 15 is on page 39?
Thanks in advance,
Erik

For everyone facing the same problem, I leave the answer here. You can access custom page enumeration via:
  pdf.pdfDocument.getPageLabels().then((pageNumbers) => {
    console.log("pageNumbers", pageNumbers);
  })

where pdf is your pdfjs-object.
Cheers,
Erik
